# Plot bar and line y columns with vastly different scales and the and the same x axis using pandas DataFrame.plot() on a single figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am making a little program to track weight loss and calorie intake.

I am trying to plot two different columns from a single `DataFrame`. Each column is a different set of y variables and they are to be plotted on the same figure using the same x axis (which is a time series). One y variable is for daily difference in weight, while the other is daily caloric intake. As you can imagine, the scales are these are quite different.

My code looks like this (it has sample data so you can test it for yourself; moreover, there may be some erroneous lines that are serving some other purpose outside of this plot):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from mplcursors import cursor
from statistics import mean

def add_nans(cals: list, dates: pd.Series) -> list:
    for cal in range(len(dates) - len(cals)):
        cals.append(np.nan)

    return cals

# Weight tracking
real_weight = [
    223.8, 222, 221.2, 220.8, 221.4, 219.4, 219.8, 219.2, 219.6, 218.2, 221.6, 220.2, 219.4, 218.8, 218, 217.4,
    218.6, 216.8, 217.6, 215.8, 216, 216, 219.6, 216.8, 216.2, 215.6, 215.8, 217.2, 214.6, 219.6, 217.4, 216.0,
    215.2, 214.2, 214.4, 216.4, 215.4, 215, 214.2, 214.4, 216, 214.2
] #### Add your weight to this list
est_cals = [
    2129, 2323, 2298, 1984, 2020, 2102, 1980, 2386, 2146, 2377, 2500, 2265, 2150, 1840, 2073, 2070, 2050, 2108,
    2130, 2770, 2170, 2270, 1955, 2030, 2020, 2500, 1910, 2150, 2695, 1980, 2110, 2190, 2940, 1970, 2750, 1870,
    2470, 2200, 2400, 4000, 2200, 1916
]
lw = len(real_weight)
dates = pd.date_range(start='01/11/2024', end='07/11/2024') #### Add date range
real_weight = add_nans(cals=real_weight, dates=dates)
est_cals = add_nans(cals=est_cals, dates=dates)
difference = [0] + [round(j-i,4) for i, j in zip(real_weight[:-1], real_weight[1:])]
goalw, startw = 185, real_weight[0] #### Add goal weight and starting weight
lin_weight = np.linspace(startw, goalw, len(dates))
lpw = round(7 * (lin_weight[0] - lin_weight[1]), 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': dates, 'lin_weight': lin_weight, 'real_weight': real_weight})
df['calories'] = est_cals
df['day'] = df.date
df['difference'] = difference
df['ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda date: date.toordinal())
df['idx'] = df.index
df = df.set_index('date')
startdt, enddt = df.index[0].date(), df.index[-1].date()
avg_dif = df.difference.abs().mean()

# Daily difference in weight
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
day = [f'day {i+1}' for i in range(len(df.index))]
df['day_1'] = day
max_day = df.loc[df['difference'] == df.difference.max(), 'day_1'].item()
min_day = df.loc[df['difference'] == df.difference.min(), 'day_1'].item()

ax1 = df[['ordinal', 'difference']].plot(x='ordinal', color='magenta', kind='bar',
              legend=True, xlabel='Days into Diet', ylabel='Difference in Daily Weight (lbs)')
ax1.axhline(y=0, linewidth=1, c='black', linestyle='-', label='_nolegend_')
ax1.set_title(f'Difference in Daily Weight from {startdt} to {df.tail(1).index.item().date()}\n')
df[['ordinal', 'calories']].plot(x='ordinal', color='darkorange', ax=ax1, linestyle='-', marker='o',
         ylabel='Daily Calorie Intake (kcal)', secondary_y=True)
ax1.set_xticklabels(day, rotation=45)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
cursor(hover=True)
plt.show()
```

Right now, this is only showing the difference bar graph, but not the caloric intake line graph on top of it, even though it has the label and ticks on the secondary y axis. I think this may have to do with scale or something, but I have tried several things and I can't get it to show up; it's either only the difference or nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

It seems that the problem arises because the default x-axes of the line and bar graphs are different in the above case, so the two graphs do not share the x-axis.

You don't have to follow my approach exactly.

edit code so that the two x-axes are unified (ticks, etc.).

```
# I edit code
ax_xticks = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
ax1 = df.reset_index(drop=True)['difference'].plot(
    color='magenta', kind='bar',legend=True, xlabel='Days into Diet', 
    ylabel='Difference in Daily Weight (lbs)', xticks=ax_xticks)

# your code
ax1.axhline(y=0, linewidth=1, c='black', linestyle='-', label='_nolegend_')
ax1.set_title(f'Difference in Daily Weight from {startdt} to {df.tail(1).index.item().date()}\n')

# I edit code
df.reset_index(drop=True)['calories'].plot(
    color='darkorange', ax=ax1, linestyle='-', marker='o', 
    ylabel='Daily Calorie Intake (kcal)', 
    secondary_y=True, legend=True, xticks=ax_xticks)
ax1.set_xticklabels([f'{i} days' for i in ax_xticks], rotation=45)

# your code
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

plot:

[image]

Comment: That solution works! Though I think I don't really understand why it was necessary in the first place? Why wasn't the x-axis shared to begin with?

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch The reason for this is unknown to me, but when plotting with datetime, the x-axis ticks and grid may be different for barplots and line plots even when plotted with same datetime of same dataset.

I thought above fact because when I changed your code both to barplots or both to lineplots, and it worked.

so I thought this might be the problem, and I edit x-axis and i find it worked.

Comment: So I guess just as a general rule, if the plot types are different, you should always reset them to a shared index?

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch I personally only use Pandas `plot` function for simple graphs. I don't use it when I need to draw subplots or secondary-yaxis graphs.